# mac: change PS1 in /etc/bashrc have no use

Tags: macos, iterm2

I use iTerm2 in mac .And I want to change the computer name.
I change the file /etc/bashrc

**before:**

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

**after**

change the PS1

```
PS1='\#\W \$'
```

save , quit and restart the iTerm2

It useless...

Comment: change the PS1='\#\W \$'

Comment: Do you have a question? Or is the a complaint...

Comment: I can not change the my name in every line ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a .bash_profile in your home directory and put your PS1 declaration there.